# Desktop software for screenshot time tracker

Tags: software, time-tracking

I researched in this SE and I found [this](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1836/desktop-software-for-time-tracking) and [this](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/4110/time-reporting-app), but this is not what I am looking for. I have various computers so 1 time tracker for 1 desktop doesn't work if I need Linux for some task and each computer is old (and the software recommendations look like a high-memory footprint).

Or for example, I use one computer for programming, one for data visualization, and one for research and communication. So I think the better software is one that takes screenshots every 10 minutes on each computer a desktop software like Greenshot, but in this case, take a screenshot and save it automatically while I am working.

This is enough for my clients to check my progress and the time spent on the task.

I am looking for a freelance recommendation because I can't trust the Internet and the software may be some time tracker that has malware and takes my money. Does anyone know?

Comment: Could you look at [search results of what you are asking for](https://www.google.com/search?q=time%20tracking%20software%20with%20screenshot%20and%20activity%20monitoring%20free) and choose a few that seem to meet your needs, then ask if anyone has experience with any of those; an open question leaves us guessing at what might be best for you.